# Fractional power of the operator $\mathcal{L}_t[t f(t)](x)$ and equivalence of divergent integrals

Tags: fractional-calculus, laplace-transform, fractional-iteration, divergent-integrals

I wonder whether an expression for fractional power of operator $\mathcal{L}_t[t f(t)](x)$ that involves Laplace transform can be derived?

I am asking this because this operator preserves the area under the function:

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\int_0^\infty\mathcal{L}_t[t f(t)](x)dx=\int_0^\infty\frac1x\mathcal{L}^{-1}_t[ f(t)](x)dx$$

But more importantly, this still works well even with divergent integrals, thus allowing us to define equivalent classes of divergent integrals. For instance, the following divergent integrals are obtained by consecutive applying this transform, and as such, can be postulated to be equal  (the first one and the third one are similar up to a shift by the way):

$\int_0^\infty\frac{\theta (x-1)}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x+1}=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^x x \text{Ei}(-x)+1}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{x-\log (x)-1}{(x-1)^2}dx$

The following plot illustrates the comparison:

[image]

So, is there a way to express fractional powers of this transform?